# Javascript global string replace with different elements from array?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm a Javascript noob using regex in javascript to globally replace text on web page. Easy enough.

```
v = v.replace(/\Simon\b/g, "JS Noob");
```

I know I can replace with functions, but I can't get this to work:

```
v = v.replace(/\bSimon\b/g, function(replaceLoop) {
    var myStringArray = ["herp","derp","clueless","hurrrrr"];
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        replaceLoop = myStringArray;
        return replaceLoop;
    } 
}
```

I have a feeling I'm thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: and the question is.....?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Also provide your input and expected output?

Comment: What does `replaceLoop` return exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick syntax error is causing issues, you are missing the closing `);` to `.replace()`.  Also, you are setting `replaceLoop = myStringArray` instead of a specific string.  Assuming you want a random index, you'll need [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

```
v = v.replace(/\bSimon\b/g, function(replaceLoop) {
    var myStringArray = ["herp","derp","clueless","hurrrrr"];
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength);

    return myStringArray[index];
});
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I had a syntax error AND a conceptual mistake. Your answer solves both... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1, make a function which returns the next item from an *Array* each time

```
function iterGen(arr, i) {
    i || (i = 0);
    return function () {
        i %= arr.length;
        return arr[i++];
    };
}
```

Step 2, pass this into your replace

```
v = v.replace(/\bSimon\b/g, iterGen(["herp","derp","clueless","hurrrrr"]));
```

Comment: Interesting, I took it as OP wanting a random index instead of iterating through with each replacement.

Comment: Starting form JS 1.7 you can simply do `var arr = [1, 2, 3], it = arr.iterator(), next = it.next.bind(it);`

Comment: @plalx I really like some things in 1.7, and many are re-designed and included in _ES 6_, but you can't rely on browser support for 1.7 - it's basically gecko only

Comment: I was unclear in my question... I was actually looking for a random index that, not really stepping through, since that would reach the end of the array. However, this is helpful and answers another question that I know I'll run into. Thank you.